# ProgressBar maximum value not working properly (Received from Array)

Tags: c#, arrays, directory, progress-bar

I'm literrally just trying to get my prgress bar to work, but I'm having issues in the sense that I can't seem to set a maximum value. My code grabs an Array.Length from an array to try get this value, but it just doesn't seem to work. I seem to be experiencing an array which gets reset halfway through reading it, so I can't get legitimate value. I've looked around, and no-one else seems to be having this issue, so I've experimented a bit. My code is as follows:

Variables:

```
public string[] oldFiles;
public string[] newFiles;
```

Function (values of inDir and outDir are just paths for directories):

```
public void Backup(string inDir, string outDir)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(outDir))
        {

            oldFiles = Directory.GetFiles(inDir); //Directory From Input
            newFiles = Directory.GetFiles(outDir); //Directory From Output
            System.IO.FileInfo oldFile;
            System.IO.FileInfo newFile;

            copyProgress.Minimum = 0;
            copyProgress.Maximum = oldFiles.Length + inDir.Length; //Problem Occurs Here
            copyProgress.Step = 1;
```

I can't seem to get an accurate value for copyProgress.Maximum from this code, or anything else I've tried. Any help is appreciated, Cheers

Comment: Could you show us your code for `.Value`?

Comment: @Silvermind Sorry I don't quite understand what you are asking me to do.

Comment: @VanMan: Silvermind is asking to show the code where you are settingthe Progressbar value.Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Using inDir.Length indeed makes no sense at all.  Progress does not depend on the length of the file name, just on the number of files you need to backup.

Comment: @Sudhakar I see, well that's it actually. The copyProgress.Minimum and Maximum was, from my understanding, all I needed to set value wise. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Hans_Passant I've used .Count() as well, but the code I've listen above is actually the closest any gets to actual copy progress the ProgressBar should be representing. Is there a better way to what I've done?

Comment: @VanMan: Progress.Minimum is used to set the minimum value for Progressbar and Maximum for setting the maximum value for it , but you have to set Progressbar.Value to some integer in between minimum to maximum so that it actullay shows the progress.

Comment: @Sudhakar I'm using copyProgress.PerformStep() rather than .Value(), Should I be using .Value()

Comment: @Van Man:no need untill unless you set the Step Value to proper progress value.

Comment: Set your minimum to 1, because I assume you perform a step in every iteration. The way you are doing it now would probably result in 1 extra progress value to set, so you would mis the last step.

Comment: @VanMan: im assuming that you want to set Maximum value to OutDir Files Length and Step value to newFiles Length.Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Sudhakar I am trying to set copyProgress.Maximum to outDir.Length (Or something like that), but I'm being told that my Step Value is wrong. Should I change it to newFiles.Length?

Comment: @VanMan: in this case i suggest to use value instead of Step. please see my answer for suggested changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace this :**

```
copyProgress.Maximum = oldFiles.Length + inDir.Length;
copyProgress.Step = 1;
```

**With Following :**

```
copyProgress.Maximum = oldFiles.Length; 
copyProgress.Value= newFiles.Length;
```

remove the call to copyProgress.PerformStep().

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to sum the old and the new folders' lengths as the maximum value for the progress bar... I'm assuming the OP just needs the progress of files to be backed up from the old folder.

Comment: @BeemerGuy This is correct, I'm just counting the new files, the ones that are coming in

Comment: The ambiguity of the OP's question made each one of us to comprehend it differently.

Comment: @BeemerGuy My apologies, there is just a lot of code in comparison to this small function, so I thought this would make the focus of my question clearer

Comment: @BeemerGuy: im assuming that VanMan wants to set Maximum value to OutDir Files Length and Step value to newFiles Count.Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @ Sudhakar How should the progress bar's value be advanced? If this is done just using ProgressBar.Value, how should this code be utilised?